# Understanding JDK 7 - try-with-resources

Tags: c#, java, java-7, try-with-resources

I am a .net developer. Recently, I picked up interest in comparing java and c#. I found Java's try-with-resources equivalent of C#'s using block. But, I could not understood it completely. I know that C#'s using block is a language feature and compiler generates code for it. I want to gain more understanding about try-with-resources and have few questions on it:

1. Is it a langauge feature similar to C#'s using block?
2. What is the equivalent JDK 6 code for the following:

   ```
   try(SomeResource resource = new SomeResource())
   {
       //Some logic
   }
   ```
3. What is the equivalent JDK 6 code for the following:

   ```
   try(SomeResource resource = new SomeResource())
   {
       //Some logic
   }
   catch(SomeException ex)
   {
   }
   ```
4. What is Java equivalent of C#'s Reflector or ILSpy tool? i.e. tool to disassemble Java byte code class files and view Java code of it.

Answer (score 7):

1. Yes, it's very similar.
2. <s>The equivalent java code is identical</s>
3. The equivalent java code is also identical
4. There are a few Java decompilers, but I quite like [JD-GUI](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui)

Update: I misread your question. The JDK6 code would look like

```
try {
    final SomeResource resource = new SomeResource();
    Throwable resourceEx = null;
    try {
      //... use resource
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        resourceEx = t;
        throw t;
    } finally {

        if(resource != null) {
            if(resourceEx != null) {
                try {
                    resource.close();
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    resourceEx.addSuppressed(t);
                }
            } else {
                resource.close();
            }
        }
    }
} catch (SomeException ex) {
//...standard error handling
}
```

Comment: Close. The initialization of resource is covered by the catch-SomeException block. Also, the resource-close logic occurs within a nested try-finally block, so that if SomeException is thrown, the resource is closed before control reaches the catch-SomeException block. See JLS 14.20.3.2 for gory details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.2

Comment: @GaryF: In your code snippet, should not the constructor of SomeResource be invoked in the try block i.e. should not it be: try { resource = new SomeResource() }.....?

Comment: You are both correct. It's actually quite a bit more involved. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @GaryF: In your code snippet what is gzip and gzipEx, where are the declarations?